# How do I properly sync data between two Windows 10 systems on the same LAN utilizing Robocopy, a .bat file, and Task Scheduler?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, sync, robocopy, task-scheduler

I've read a number of posts regarding the use of robocopy to sync data between two Windows systems. I tried various configurations, and the settings I currently have in place are what seemed to work best for most users.

System A runs Windows 10 Home, and its desktop is shared to a Microsoft user account w/ full privileges.
System B runs Windows 10 Pro, and its desktop is shared to same Microsoft user account w/ full privileges.

The .bat files were stored on each system's respective desktop and scheduled to run every three minutes.

System_A sync.bat:

```
cd C:\Users\username\Desktop  
robocopy C:\Users\username\Desktop\directory_to_sync '\\System_B\Desktop\directory_to_sync' /E /MIR /mt /z
```

System B sync.bat:

```
cd C:\Users\username\OneDrive\Desktop  
robocopy C:\Users\username\OneDrive\Desktop\directory_to_sync '\\System_A\Desktop\directory_to_sync' /E /MIR /mt /z
```

Using System_A's sync.bat as an example, I set the task to run w/ highest privileges, and I configured it for Windows 10, since it defaulted to Vista/Server 2008.  I triggered it to run at task creation/modification, and repeat every three minutes indefinitely, only stopping if the task were to run longer than three hours.  I set it active to a time earlier this morning, and I synched it across time zones.

The Actions Tab is where most of the posts I'd read had made changes and saw varying degrees of success.
My configuration is as follows:

Action: Start a program
Program/script: cmd
Add arguments (optional): /c sync.bat (Note: The /c was auto-added by Windows for whatever reason.)
Start in (optional): C:\Users\username\Desktop

The job history reports that it completes w/ an operational code of 2, but nothing is synched.  I'm out of ideas, so any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: Windows network paths always start with a double backslash -> `'\\System_B\...` Do you sync the data for backup reasons or just to have the files accessible at both systems? If it is the latter may be just mounting the share as drive on one and using the other as file server may be more suitable instead of syncing them every three minutes.

Comment: My bad, that was a typo in the post.  The scripts actually have double backslashes. 
Thank you for pointing this out.  I'll correct it right now.

Comment: It was actually a formatting error on my part, but it's resolved now.
I'm doing this to have both directories accessible on both systems.  I thought about mounting the drives, which I originally did, but I'd really like to be able to sync this particular directory.

Comment: It's a very very bad idea to run concurrent jobs on two computers this way. One job will do one update, while the other destroys its file. This is asking for trouble.

Comment: I suggest looking into a proper two-way sync software instead, like Syncthing or whatever.

Comment: @harrymc How would I then go about synching the data between these two systems?  Should I simply stagger the tasks, so they aren't running concurrently?